# Reference for MongoDB runCommand with optional parameters

Tags: mongodb

I need to know where I can find the reference resource for MongoDB runCommand.

i.e. what kind of commands are available and what kind of optional parameters each command can use.

For example,

```
db.runCommand({addshard: "10.0.4.85:27020", allowLocal : 1, maxSize:2, minKey: 1, maxKey:10});
```

Thank you

// Update //

maxSize is documented here [maxSize](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Configuring+Sharding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [MongoDB Command Reference](http://www.10gen.com/static/downloads/mongodb_qrc_commands.pdf) (PDF) for a list of the most frequently used.  Also, to get a full list, the card also provides this tip:

> To get a list of all commands available on your version of the server,
>   run **mongod --rest** and then visit **http://localhost:28017/_commands** in
>   your  web browser